# Is there a way to run my XBAP (or WPF) application as OLE object?

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, .net-4.0, ole, xbap

I need to run my WPF application as OLE object. I apologize that if I make it XBAP-application I could, but how?

Generally I need this cause of I need to access my application from [CIMPLICITY](http://www.ge-ip.com/products/2819).

Comment: Do you need your app. written with WPF to be embedded and exposed in CIMPLICITY as  OLE (ActiveX) object?

Comment: @Arseny; I don't know anything about CIMPLICITY, but my colleague says that it's only way to run WPF app in CIMPLICITY is expose it as OLE object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your existed .NET application to be COM visible. it's a quite general question and I may suggest to look at [.NET - COM Interoperability](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/COM_DOTNET_INTEROP.aspx) and [Microsoft .NET/COM Migration and Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817653.aspx). I'm sure there is a very popular issue and you can find much more materials about it.